# PHP CSV-Upload UTF-8 (with and without BOM)

Tags: php, csv, file-upload, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Can someone perhaps explain me the difference - and how to recognize or change the format?

I've a simple HTML-Upload-Form and after uploading I parse the file contents with fgetcsv(). After parsing I've an array like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["OrderId"]=>
    string(13) "FG-456887"
    ["Product"]=>
    string(7) "B9876"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["OrderId"]=>
    string(13) "FG-852562"
    ["Product"]=>
    string(7) "B9877"
   }
}
```

var_dump() shows me (apparently) exactly the same dump, when using files with or without BOM, but when I make a simple loop over this array and check if the OrderId (first field in the CSV) is empty - this always fails, when the CSV is encoded without BOM. When I save the same file with BOM - everything works fine.

```
foreach ($data as $position) {
   $orderid = $position["﻿OrderId"];
   if (empty($orderid)) die('No orderid found');
}
```

And it is only the first field - the other fields are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself. Don't know, if it's elegant - but it works...

```
function remove_utf8_bom($text) {
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=';', $seperator = '"') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
            return FALSE;

    $csvdata = file($filename);
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($csvdata as $line) {
        $row = remove_utf8_bom($line);
        $row = str_getcsv($row,$delimiter,$seperator);
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**

Unbeknownst to me I was in the same situation. I only realized it when I could not use the data that I imported from csv files.

**Problem:**

While importing two columns from a CSV file I could not access the data in the first column in the array:

```
array() => ['project_nr' => '0000000', 'project_name']
```

**I tried:**

```
array_keys($myArray);
```

And it worked as expected, but not until further analysis did I see that the first column 'project_nr' was 13 characters and not 10 characters. Which I later realized was BOM being read in.

**Solution:**

```
$str = file_get_contents('yourfile.utf8.csv');
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 === strncmp($str, $bom, 3)) {
   echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";
   $str = substr($str, 3);
}
```

**Reference:**

[Here is where I found the solution](https://anupamsaha.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/detecting-utf-byte-order-mark-using-php/)

**Anecdote:**

I placed this solution here in hopes of connecting google searches for not being able to access specific keys in an array to BOM UTF8 CSV upload.(which is what I needed and was not able to find) I hope that perhaps it may be of help to some desperately searching soul.